# preg_replace: invalid range

Tags: php

Подскажите как решить:

> PHP Warning:  `preg_replace()`: Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 40

```
$temp_str = preg_replace('/[^а-яА-ЯіІєЄїЇґҐa-zA-Z0-9_-\d ]/ui',"", $str);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знак `-` надо экранировать иначе получается некорректный диапазон `_-\d`.

Comment: можно еще в конец его поставить